# I am trying to backup a database and am getting MSG 3013

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, backup, ssms

I have tried to backup in Microsoft SSMS with the GUI backup task, and it fails after a few seconds, so then I tried running this command:

```
BACKUP DATABASE databasename TO DISK = 'd:\databasename_full.Bak' WITH FORMAT, MEDIANAME = 'd_datbasenamebackup', NAME = 'Full Backup of databasename';
```

And get a very generic error of the following

```
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

I am wondering if anyone has come across this error before. Everything I have read is saying there is a media fault, which I know isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Microsoft support page for this Error Message 3013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290787).
 It is apparently caused when a filemark in your backup device could not be read. Resolution steps below:

> To allow SQL Server to perform new backups to the backup device, you
>   must manually delete or erase the device by using the following
>   command:

```
BACKUP DATABASE mydatabase TO DISK='C:\MyDatabase.bak' with FORMAT
```

Comment: I have tried that, still get the same error.

If you read my statement, I did put WITH FORMAT in my statement.

Comment: I also tried saving to an external drive on my personal laptop from the server via a unc path, and that didn't work. So, my guess is there is something wrong with the database itself.